# .toggleclass and .slidetoggle don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all, I've read all the topics about this issue and couldn't find a solution. Basically I'm trying to apply a simple nested gridview in my MVC project. It all works fine except the expand/collapse function. I implement it with this script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var size = $("#main #gridT > thead > tr > th").size(); // get total column
                $("#main #gridT > thead > tr > th").last().remove(); // remove last column header
                $("#main #gridT > thead > tr").prepend("<th></th>"); // add one column at first for collapsible column
                $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {
                    $(this).prepend(
                            $("<td></td>")
                            .addClass("hoverEff")
                            .addClass("expand")
                            .attr('title', "click for show/hide")
                        );

                    //now get sub table from last column and add this to the next new added row
                    var table = $("table", this).parent().html();
                    //add new row with this subtable
                    $(this).after("<tr><td></td><td style='padding:5px; margin:0px;' colspan='" + (size - 1) + "'>" + table + "</td></tr>");
                    $("table", this).parent().remove();
```

-->>>Up until this point everything works smoothly.

```
      //// add click event for make collapsible
                $(".hoverEff", this).live('click', function () {
                    alert($(".hoverEff").parent().closest("tr").next().text());
                    $(".hoverEff").parent().closest("tr").next().slidetoggle(100);
                    $(".hoverEff").toggleclass("expand collapse");
                });
            });
            //by default make all subgrid in collapse mode
            $("#main #gridt > tbody > tr td.expand").each(function (i, el) {
                $(this).toggleclass("expand collapse");
                $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slidetoggle(100);
            });

        });
```

When I open my page, subgrids are not collapsed, and when I click on the button, it doesn't trigger anything. I tried to check if the function is working with this code:

```
alert($(".hoverEff").parent().closest("tr").next().text());
```

and it is. I've also heard that inline elements cannot be affected by a .slidetoggle, but my element is a tr inside a table. I've also heard that .live is deleted in jQuery 2.0.0, but I have jQuery 3.0.0 installed through NuGet. I can't trigger .on('click') event and I'm starting to think I've messed up something in the bundle rendering.

My grid:

```
<div class="inner" id="inner2">
        <div id="main" style="padding:25px; background-color:white;">
            @grid.GetHtml(
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridT", width = "700px" },
            columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("singleUser.RA_Responsible_Person", "RA Responsible Person"),
                    grid.Column("singleUser.Issues_Count", "Issues Count"),
                    grid.Column(header: "Min Deadline", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.singleUser.Min_Deadline)),
                    grid.Column(header: "Max Deadline", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", item.singleUser.Max_Deadline)),

                    grid.Column(format: (item) =>
                    {
                        WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.Cases);
                        return subGrid.GetHtml(
                            htmlAttributes: new { id = "subT" },
                            columns: subGrid.Columns(
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_ID", "Issue_ID"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue", "Issue"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Case_Status", "Case_Status"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issued_by", "Issued_by"),
                                    subGrid.Column("Issue_Date", "Issue_date"),
                                )
                            );
                    })
        )
    )
        </div>
```

Please assist! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used google graphs in this page earlier and added jquery as a library through a link to googleapis. I removed it and I think all the functions stopped working, but it's a start.

I'll make another issue with a different content.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any console errors?

I believe that toggleclass should be toggleClass should it not? The same with slideToggle?

Comment: Of course they are. Thanks a lot! 

Anyway, when I run the script now it doesn't function properly. When I click on the icon, it triggers collapse for all buttons and suddenly I don't see the icons anymore.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, were there any console error before or after the clicks events?

Comment: Sorry, it says:
"Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead." and "no element found". I may have copied other elements incorectly...

Comment: is the getPreventDefault() somewhere else in your code, or in a library that you have included? Is it a warning or error? Is everything after the click event failing or just the click event itself?

Comment: it is after the click, the click works (strangely enough). getPreventDefault() is not the code under question. The classes and id names look OK. "//by default make all subgrid in collapse mode code snippet" doesn't function correctly. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: yes, it is. Maybe getPreventDefault() is connected to it somehow.

Comment: If it is an error it could be stopping the rest of the js firing correctly, if you can correct that issue it might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Yeah I see this error on the other pages too, so it shouldn't be a big problem if I managed to run so much js as I have on my site. It must be something else.

Comment: Okay, I think I've found the root of the problem. I used google graphs in this page earlier and added jquery as a library through a link to googleapis. I removed it and I think all the functions stopped working, but it's a start.

Comment: Good work once these related issues are sorted we may be able to help further!